# How do I make the following input areas expand until the end of the screen?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is a Bootstrap-like form:

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group row-group">
        <label class="col-6">First name</label>
        <input class="col-6" type="text" value=""></input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row-group">
        <label class="col-6">Last name</label>
        <input class="col-6" type="text" value=""></input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group row-group">
        <label class="col-4">Message</label>
        <input class="col-8" type="text" value=""></input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group row-group">
        <label class="col-4">Message</label>
        <input class="col-12" type="text" value=""></input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row-group">
        <label class="col-4">Message</label>
        <input class="col-12" type="text" value=""></input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row-group">
        <label class="col-4">Message</label>
        <input class="col-12" type="text" value=""></input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 row-group">
        <button class="btn">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  display: flex
}

.row-group {
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row !important
  align-items: center

  label {
    flex: 0 0 100px
  }

  input {
    flex: 1
  }
}

.form-group {
  flex: 1 0 0
  flex-direction: column
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

I want the inputs of the first row and third row to reach the end of the container div (to not to stack horizontally with its neigbhor).

I tried this:

```
.row-group {
  input: flex: 1 1 100%
}
```

But nothing moves.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by `bootstrap like form`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out this Fiddle - is this what you're going for?
https://jsfiddle.net/jspruance/1p739t1h/

Here's the modified CSS:

```
.row {
  xdisplay: flex;
}

.row-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  align-items: center;
}

  label {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
  }

  input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: 1;
  }

.form-group {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

I fixed a few problems with the CSS:
1) Extra close bracket after input element
2) Missing bracket after .row-group
3) Added 'width: 100%' property and 'box-sizing: border-box'
4) Floated label left.
5) Commented out 'display: flex' on .row ( not needed)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, disregard the comment about the float - looks like I ended up removing that.